# what does ARG_MAX mean when I run a script?

Tags: linux, unix

Up to now I know what `ARG_MAX` means (thanks to [EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77409118/how-to-check-if-file-names-match-and-then-if-nth-column-of-both-files-match-then?noredirect=1#comment136472829_77409341)):

```
ls foo bar
```

The command is `ls` and it has three arguments: `foo`,   and `bar`. It's 7 characters, so the arguments of `ls` in here is `7`.

Now let's suppose this is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

while read -r do_something
do
    if [ "$do_something" == "some_string" ]
    then
        echo "do_something $do_something equals to some_string."
    fi
done < some_file

/usr/bin/python3 generate_numbers.py

names="$(awk '{print $4}' another_file.txt)"

awk 'BEGIN { for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) print i }'

if [ "$(stat -c %s mail.txt)" -g '0' ]
then
    echo -e "These are mailing list:\n\n$(cat mail.txt)" | mail -s "Mails List - $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"
```

Now with the above sample, when I run `bash /home/file` or `/home/file`, what's the arguments counts?

- Is that `wc -c file` which is `459` (the shebang is excluded)?
- Is that for each command? For example the `while` has `166`, `/usr/bin/python3` has `20`, and so on.

I think it is the second assumption because it's not logical the first one since I see some huge bash (or any other) scripts which are more than `2097152` in my server (this number is the output of `getconf ARG_MAX`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120642/13792

Comment: I believe ARG_MAX is designed to be the maximum number of bytes that can be contained in the executable name + all arguments + the operating environment for the invocation. Note that it looks like this setting no longer impacts execution the way it once did, so may not be particularly relevant to whatever you are actually trying to determine